# Nginx win server 2012 - Configure proxy pass

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have a node server listening on localhost:8080 and I'd like to use nginx as proxy pass, so i made nginx listen to port 80 incoming connections. However I'm not able to configure nginx config to do the reverse proxying. I do not currently have a domain, only server IP. So I'm guessing server_name has to be set to $host or something?

```html
events{

}
http{
 server{
     listen 80;    
     location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
       proxy_set_header Host 127.0.0.1;
}

  }
}
```

If I try to visit my server IP on port 80 I just receive welcome to Nginx page.

Comment: `nginx` is not seeing your new configuration file - the welcome page is from another configuration file, possibly called `default`. Try `nginx -t` or `nginx -T` and have a look at the error log.

Comment: Its using the config file I made and it tested it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should reload and restart your nginx

`sudo service nginx reload
sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: I'm using windows server, as stated in title.